# How to #define if in C++ to be python-like

Tags: python, c++, if-statement, c-preprocessor

I know that I can define something like

`#define LESS(x, y) if(x < y)`

so I wonder can I define `if` in c++ to be python-like template or not? such as

`if x < y: do something` instead of `if(x < y) do something`

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: I don't think you can easily do it, because any macro you add would probably take parenthesis as well. I'm with @segfolt though: why would you want to do that (outside of obfuscated c++ contests)

Comment: @utnapistim: Excuse my poor English. English is not my native language :( I'll be careful in future posts.

Comment: @segfolt, I was not criticizing your English (sorry if it sounded that way). I just don't see why you want to do that (although after writing python code I sometimes want to do the same). You can use `and`, `or` and `not` though, instead of `&&`, `||` and `!` in conditions.

Comment: The closest you can come: `#define IF if( #define THEN )` followed by `IF x<y THEN do something;`. But the error messages will be unreadable.

Comment: My new favorite question ;)

Answer (score 1):

To put it shortly - **no**.

from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/):

> When the preprocessor encounters this directive, it replaces any occurrence of identifier in the rest of the code by replacement. This replacement can be an expression, a statement, a block or simply anything. The preprocessor does not understand C++, it simply replaces any occurrence of identifier by replacement.

What you want is something like this

```
#define if(x):(y) if(x){##y##};
```

Nevertheless, colon is a keyword and can't be used for identifier, so it breaks your macro definition. There's no way to escape it.

Comment: ... And that's not a technicality. Macro names must follow the syntax for identifiers, all keywords follow the syntax for identifiers, and a colon does not.